# ssh_exchange_identification error when using Node 8.11 but not when using Node 4.7

Tags: node.js, npm, ssh

I have both Node 8.11 and Node 4.7 installed on my Windows 10 box. When, in a new project, I try run 'npm install' with Node 8.11, I receive the following error:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Development\Git\2.16.2\bin\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/ev1stensberg/generator.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

If I use Node 4.7, the installations run without error. I'm not sure what I should 'fix' in the new node environment to get this to work.

Both environments show the same '.npmrc' file when I try `npm config edit`

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

This message indicates the remote SSH server is accepting the TCP connection from your client, then immediately closing the connection. The client and server haven't exchanged any keys, passwords, or other information yet. It suggests one of two things is going on:

1. The remote SSH server is configured not to accept connections from your host.
2. Some firewall or other network device is interfering with the TCP connection.

It looks like the remote host is apparently Github, and you say it happens with one program but not with another program on the same host. Given that, my guess is that you have some software on your local Windows system which is permitting one NPM installation to work, but not the other installation. This software might be part of a malware protection package, for example.

Comment: In both instances, I'm using `npm install`. In one case, it's the one supplied with version 4.7.x of node.js. In the other it's 8.11. What I was hoping is that someone knew what difference between the two versions might cause just this situation.